# How to break up long words but leave out short ones?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to wrap text to fit inside it's parent element however I'm having issues with the text as seen in the below image.

[image: Image to show word break]

On the left side, the word 'Against' is broken up and is harder to read though on the right side, the single word is too long and so is correctly broken up to fit within it's parent. Here is the code to support this:

**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <div class="icon">
        <h5>D</h5>
    </div>
    <p class="label">Defending Ourselves Against Infectious Diseases</p>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="icon">
        <h5>D</h5>
    </div>
    <p class="label">DefendingOurselvesAgainstInfectiousDiseases</p>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.label {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

I would preferably like the left side to display the text without breaks and the right side to display with breaks (and a hyphen to show that it is broken) as the word is too long.

A CSS solution would be better though I think the only way to solve this is with Javascript. How would I fix this text issue?

**EDIT**

Also, I cannot just use a `<br>` tag because I would like this to apply to many other elements like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `word-break` rule with `word-wrap: break-word`.

```css
li {
    max-width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="icon">
             <h5>D</h5>
        </div>
        <p class="label">Defending Ourselves Against Infectious Diseases</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="icon">
             <h5>D</h5>
        </div>
        <p class="label">DefendingOurselvesAgainstInfectiousDiseases</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But how to add hyphen?

Comment: @DFayet `word-break` [only accepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) `normal`, `break-all` or `keep-all`. If some browser supports `word-break: break-word` it's non-standard.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add the hyphen with CSS alone.

Comment: CSS hyphenation [has quite questionable support](http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphen), but I guess using it wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Use **word-wrap** instead of **word-break**.

If you have to cut some extra texts then there is

1. ***text-overflow:ellipsis***;
2. **word-wrap: break-word;**  (Only in IE7)

I found a good Article:

http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/
http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/

**JS**

```
<div id="myDIV">GIVE YOUR TEXT</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myDIV").style.wordWrap = "break-word";
}
</script>
```